# Azure Load Balancer Remove HTTP Probe

Tags: powershell, azure

How do I remove the `HTTP probe` from the `Azure Load Balancer` ?

The problem is when I redirect to our `HTTPS` the load balancer is killing the HTTP site.

This is the output from the Get-AzureEndpoint powershell command -

```
LBSetName     : HTTP-80
LocalPort     : 80
Name          : HTTP
Port          : 80
Protocol      : tcp
Vip           : 137.135.130.248
ProbePath     : /
ProbePort     : 80
ProbeProtocol : http
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: How does your code reply to HTTP probe request?

Answer (score 0):

Late answer for the benefit of anyone arriving here from a search engine.
See the detailed answer from Craig Landis in this post:
 http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/04589d2d-4acb-4f86-a2d0-957dc2a73a4f/endpoints-not-working-dns-scans-them

The powershell script from that post to create an endpoint without HTTP probing is:
`get-azurevm myvm | add-azureendpoint -name web -protocol TCP -publicport 80 -localport 80 | update-azurevm`